# kubernetes - can't access the cluster with new user certificate

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, certificate, tls1.2, createuser

I want to create new user admin in kubernetes ,i do all the steps for creating and authorizing the certificates but when i want to access to api,i receive anuthorized error.
i do these steps to create user-admin:

1/ `openssl genrsa -out user.key 2048`

2/ `openssl req -new -key user.key -out user.csr -subj "/CN=kube-user"`

3/

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CertificateSigningRequest
metadata:
  name: user
spec:
  request: $(cat user.csr | base64 | tr -d '\n')
  usages:
  - digital signature
  - key encipherment
  - server auth
EOF
```

4/ `k certificate approve user`

5/ `k get csr user -o jsonpath='{.status.certificate}' | base64 --decode > user.crt`

6/ `kubectl config view -o jsonpath='{.clusters[0].cluster.certificate-authority-data}' --raw | base64 --decode - > ca.crt`

7/

```
curl https://$Kube-Master-Ip:6443/api/v1 \
 --key user.key \
 --cert user.crt \
 --cacert ca.crt
```

8/ and this is what i've receive:

```
{
"kind":"Status",
"apiVersion":"v1",
"metadata":{},
"status":"Failure",
"message":"Unauthorized",
"reason":"Unatuhorized",
"code":401
}
```

> > document source: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The step 2 command is wrong. The admin user should be part of system:masters group.

```
openssl req -new -key user.key -out user.csr -subj "/CN=kube-user/O=system:masters"
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer , I'm just stuck in this problem to saved me...

Comment: Is there any good resource to fully understand these topics?(These are so confusing to me.)

Comment: This would help you understand the groups for all k8s components. https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/master/docs/04-certificate-authority.md